# How can you launch a debug session from a msbuild task?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

The system i'm building has 4 separate applications that in production, are 4 distinct win32 services.  During development I run them as 4 separate console applications.  These programs need to be started in a specific order.

I do this from VS2010 by right clicking on each project and select debug > start a new instance.  This works but is painfully slow.

I attempted to use run "Multiple startup projects", but they all start at the same time. Changing the start order does not help.

So, what i want to do is to use MSBuild to start each program from a build script.  I attempted to use the Exec Task but the programs are not launched as debugged processes..

Since all of VS is based on msbuild, i know there must be a way to launch a project this way..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mix of Pre/Post build events for this. You can modify them in `Project Properties -> Build Events` for the last project.

**Prebuild event**

```
// Build is going to replace these files, they must not be in use  
taskkill /IM Foo.exe  
taskkill /IM Bar.exe
```

**Postbuild event**

```
// VsJITDebugger will ask for which debugger to attach, you can 
// choose currently active VS instance
VsJITDebugger.exe $(SolutionDir)\Foo\bin\Debug\Foo.exe  
VsJITDebugger.exe $(SolutionDir)\Bar\bin\Debug\Bar.exe
```

Launching debugger on each build may get bit annoying :) Better would be to use a batch script for the last project. You can do it in `Project Properties -> Debug -> Start external program`.

Comment: Arun,

The VsJitDebugger ran the program as a Windows application and not a Console application. A Brown/Grey window appears and then the app crashes. This is the same behavioral i get if i just try to double click the application from explorer. I tried the same thing from msbuild command and got the same results. I dont see a way to launch VSjitDebugger to exec a console app.

However, my desired approach is to do this from a build script that i run from the Tools > External tools menu.

Comment: It works for me though, I created a External Tool command [img](http://i.imgur.com/BcNtL.png). VSJitDebugger shows up a dialog to choose the instance of VS debugger to attach the console app: [img](http://i.imgur.com/xaT1C.png)

Comment: Arun, thanks for the feedback. I gave up and put in a hardcoded sleep value into each service.  Its only compiled at DEBUG time..

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a solution.. I put a different hard-coded delay into each app and launched it with Debug "multiple start-up projects"..  A bit of a hack but simple is better.